# Are Multi-column Primary Keys in MySQL a optimisation problem?

Tags: mysql, key

Been looking into using multi-column primary keys and as performance is extremely important with the size of traffic and database I need to know if there is anything to consider before I start throwing out the unique ID method on many of my tables and start using mulit column primary keys.

So, what are the performance/optimisation pros/cons to using multi column primary keys versus a basic single column, auto-inc primary key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't think that there would be any performance problems with multiple primary keys. It's more or less equivalent to having multiple indexes (you will spend a little bit more time computing index values when doing inserts).

Sometimes the data model makes more sense with multiple keys. I'd worry about being straightforward first and worry about performance second. You can always add more indexes, improve your queries, or twiddle server settings.

I think the most I've encountered was a 4-column primary key. Makes me cringe a little bit, but it worked¹.

---

[1] "worked" is defined to mean "*the application performed to specification*", and is not meant to imply that actual tasks were accomplished using said application. :)

Answer (score 2):

Is there a particular reason that you need/want to use multi-column keys instead of an (I assume) already created single-column key?

One of the problems with [Natural Keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key) is dealing with cascading an update to the key value across all the foreign keys.  A surrogate key such as an auto-increment column avoids this.

In terms of performance, depending on the row count, the data types of the columns, your storage engine, and the amount of RAM you have dedicated to MySQL, multi-column keys can affect performance due to the sheer size of the index.

In my experience, it is almost always easier in terms of development and maintenance to use a surrogate key as the PK and then create indexes that cover your queries across the natural keys.  However, the only way to determine the true performance impact for your application is to benchmark it with realistic a realistic load and dataset.

HTH -

Chris